# grep after grep : No such file or directory

Tags: bash, grep

To create a test file contains blanks in the filename first:

```
vim  "/tmp/it is a test.txt"
bash  escape
```

Search with grep:

```
grep    -lr   'bash'  /tmp
/tmp/it is a test.txt
```

I want to grep command after the grep:

```
grep    -lr   'bash'  /tmp  | xargs grep  escape
grep: /tmp/it: No such file or directory
grep: is: No such file or directory
grep: a: No such file or directory
grep: test.txt: No such file or directory
```

So i add `-0` in xargs:

```
grep    -lr   'bash'  /tmp | xargs -0 grep  escape
grep: /tmp/it is a test.txt
: No such file or directory
```

I find the reason:

```
grep    -lr   'bash'  /tmp | xargs -0 
grep: /tmp/it is a test.txt
#a blank line at the bottom
```

`xargs -0` add a blank line!
How can suppress the output  `: No such file or directory` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may have guessed, the first version you tried

```
grep -lr 'bash' /tmp | xargs grep escape
```

failed because [`xargs`](https://ss64.com/bash/xargs.html) assumes arguments taken from standard input are delimited by:

> space, tab, newline and end-of-file.

You were on the good track by adding the `-0` CLI option:

```
grep -lr 'bash' /tmp | xargs -0 grep escape
```

But to make it fully working, you'll also need to ensure that `xargs`'s input is indeed delimited by `NUL` characters.

Hence the following command that relies on [`tr`](https://ss64.com/bash/tr.html):

```
grep -lr 'bash' /tmp | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 grep escape
```

Alternatively, a better solution amounts to directly using [`grep`](https://ss64.com/bash/grep.html)'s `--null` CLI option:

```
grep -lr --null 'bash' /tmp | xargs -0 grep escape
```

or more concisely:

```
grep -lrZ 'bash' /tmp | xargs -0 grep escape
```

#### As an aside

> I find the reason:
> `xargs -0` add a blank line!

To explain this further:

`xargs -0` alone amounts to `xargs -0 echo`, and because of `-0`, `xargs` sees the final **newline** printed by `grep` (included as you didn't use the `--null` CLI option) as a character that is part of the filename… which is then printed by `echo`.

Answer (score 1):

`grep` has the option `-s` or `--no-messages` to  suppress error messages about nonexistent or unreadable files.